# Set width of div to full page

Tags: html, css

Hello i have a landing page. I would like to set width of my header to the full page with bootstrap. I was trying to set it with container-fluid class but its not working. How to fix this? That it will be responsive and width set to the full page? Thanks for Help

Here is the code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,200;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,600&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,200;0,700;0,900;1,600&display=swap');
.raleway600 {
  font-family: raleway, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: italic;
}

.raleway900 {
  font-family: raleway, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 4em;
}

* {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 60px;
  width: 98%;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 10rem;
}


/* fix padding under menu after resize */

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 110px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
}

footer {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(11, 11, 11);
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  width: 7rem;
  height: 7rem;
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin-left: 17em !important;
}

#banner {
  position: relative;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("logo");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}

.row-fluid {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center !important;
}

.img-responsive {
  margin: 0 auto
}

nav {
  overflow: auto;
}

header {
  height: 100vh;
}

.card-img-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15vw;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="banner" class="container-fluid baner p-0  ">
    <div class="hero-text">
      <h1 class="raleway900">"Text 1"</h1>
      <p class="raleway600"><strong>Text 2</strong></p>
      <p class="raleway600"><strong>Text 3</strong></p>
      <p class="raleway600"><strong>Text 4</strong> </p>
      <p class="raleway600"><strong>Text 5</strong> </p>
      <button class="btn btn-primary raleway600">Button 1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-light raleway600">Button 2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j28qyhrw/1/

Comment: Is the header in a container? If so, there is your problem.

Comment: If I'm correct, you need your `<header>` full width? Because it is a block element, it is already full width. You could use the bootstrap utility class like `.w-100` just to make it sure ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have it, hope it helps

```
<div class="header container-fluid d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="d-flex">
        <li>
          <a href="" title="">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="" title="">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="" title="">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="" title="">Link 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="hamburger-menu-wrap ">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <header class="banner container-fluid border-bottom">
    <div class="banner1">
      <p>Header 1</p>
      <p>Header 2</p>
      <p>Header 3</p>
      <p>Header 4</p>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="main-container container-fluid">
    <p>Content 1</p>
    <p>Content 2</p>
    <p>Content 3</p>
    <p>Content 4</p>
    <p>Content 5</p>

  </div>

  <footer class="footer container-fluid text-center">
    <p class=" pb-0">Footer</p>
  </footer>
```

```
/* header */
.header{ background-color: #2b2d3b; color: #fff; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; }
.header nav ul{ list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; background-color: #2b2d3b; color: #fff; }
.header nav ul li{ list-style: none; padding:0 ; margin: 0 15px; color: #fff; }
.header nav ul li a{ color: #fff; }

/* hamburger menu */
.hamburger-menu-wrap {width: 24px;height: 16px;cursor: pointer;z-index: 1;display: none;}
.hamburger-menu-wrap span {background: #fff;display: block;height: 2px;margin-bottom: 6px;width: 100%;float: right;cursor: pointer !important;}

@media(max-width:991px){
    .hamburger-menu-wrap{ display: block; }
    .header nav{ display: none; }
    .hamburger-open .header nav{ display: flex; }
    .hamburger-open .header nav ul{ flex-direction: column!important; }
}

.footer{ background-color: #2b2d3b; color: #fff; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; }
```

Or check in jsfiddle example link :
https://jsfiddle.net/DeveloperSandip/u6ph27cx/4/

Comment: This did not help me, nothing has changed. I want to set only my header section to full width.There is an img and i want it to be wide for full page.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hidden brand</a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex">
              <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      
       <div class="container-fluid p-md-5 p-5 m-md-auto">
        <div class="text-center" id="">
            <img id="logo" style="pointer-events:none;" src="" class="img-fluid g-md-5 p-md-5" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

try
Responsive containers allow you to specify a class that is 100% wide until the specified breakpoint is reached, after which we apply max-widths for each of the higher breakpoints. For example, .container-sm is 100% wide to start until the sm breakpoint is reached, where it will scale up with md, lg, xl, and xxl.[Watch the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4Jgb.jpg)

hope it will help you

> Why do you use your own css  for it? I don't have much experience yet, it's possible that I misunderstood. It is enough to insert the cdn in the head - I thought. Could it be that your css file conflicts with Bootstrap?

Comment: It didnt work. idk maybe im doing something wrong. Right now i have class container-fluid and its not wide for full page. I want only set my header section where is an img to be wide for whole page. when i set 100vw it works but, img is not in center. Thanks for helping